# How to convert Image to Bitmap form java application to android device

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I wrote a java application that creates some Images from a webcam and their format is `java.awt.Image`.  I want to show those images on my Android device however, ADK doesn't include `java.awt`.

I want to convert it in the java application and show the image in Android by converting the Image to a Bitmap then transfer it to Android via a socket connection.

I Googled for a solution and some examples used `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` but it seems to be of no use in this situation.

/////  2012/4/15 added////////////

I use this ,but don't works , is there any wrong with it

/////OUTPUT/////

`ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    int len =data.length;
    oos.writeInt(len);
    oos.flush();
    oos.write(data);
    oos.flush();`

/////INPUT/////

`int size =dis.readInt();
    byte []data=new byte[size];
    dis.read(data);
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert Image to JPEG or PNG byte array and send that. InputStream can be decoded on Android.

Comment: I use this ,but don't works , it's there any wrong with it

/////OUTPUT/////
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
try {
 ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();  
int len =data.length;
oos.writeInt(len);
oos.flush();
oos.write(data);
oos.flush();


/////INPUT/////
int size =dis.readInt();
byte []data=new byte[size];
dis.read(data);
image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this: [Savin bitmap files in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip60.html?page=2)

In the code, you can replace the file with a buffer, send it and load it on Android like you would from a file.